# AMD Dual-Core Processor C-50, AMD Radeon HD 6250 graphics not support in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FLGRX (AMD Catalyst) driver issues in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142627/flgrx-amd-catalyst-driver-issues-in-ubuntu-12-04)

failed install ATI/AMD proprietary FGLAX graphics driver(post-release update) from Additional Drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post release won't install, if you want the latest, download directly from AMD site and install.

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide

I am running Catalyst 12.1 on my ASUS 1015B netbook which has C50 and AMD6250, with xvba-va driver, I can watch full HDMI video with VLC.