# Ubuntu 13.10 screen flashing and is not going to login screen after I installed AMD Catalyst driver

Tags: 13.10, catalyst

So I installed the AMD Catalyst driver, rebooted and then the screen started to shift between black screen and normal screen every ~5 sec. Also it does not go to the normal login screen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post:
[FLGRX (AMD Catalyst) driver issues in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142627/flgrx-amd-catalyst-driver-issues-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)

It's for 12.04, but it should also work on 13.10.